# Error on mysql if query

Tags: mysql

I get the error below when i try to run the query below. some one help pls!

```
 IF EXISTS (SELECT * 
               FROM sch_scores s2 
               WHERE s2.ResultID = "24614" 
                 AND s2.FormatID = "9" 
                 )
    BEGIN
       UPDATE sch_scores 
       SET Score = '4' 
       WHERE ResultID = "24614" 
         AND FormatID = "9" 
        )
    END 
    ELSE BEGIN
       INSERT INTO dbo.sch_scores (school_id, ScoreID, ResultID, FormatID, Score, Status)
       VALUES (1, 30836, 24614, 9, 4, 'Active') 
    END

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sch_scores s2 WHERE s2.Result' at line 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Control flow structures like `IF` or `WHILE` and so on can only be used in stored procedures or functions. Either you put your code in a stored procedure or what you're really looking for might be `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`. Read more about it [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html).

Though it really seems you need an `insert...on duplicate key` statement, many examples for stored procedures can be found in the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-procedure.html).

Comment: How do put the code in a stored procedure? pls... maybe a little more explanation

Comment: @EmmanuelChiemelie Edited my answer to include a link with examples.

Answer (score 0):

You need to surround ResultID, FormatID and Score with quotes as you did with the WHERE clauses:

VALUES (1, 30836, '24614', '9', '4', 'Active')

Comment: IF EXISTS (SELECT * 
           FROM sch_scores
           WHERE ResultID = '24614'
             AND FormatID = '9' 
             AND Score = '4')
BEGIN
   UPDATE sch_scores 
   SET Score = '4' 
   WHERE ResultID = "24614" 
     AND FormatID = "9" 
     AND Score = "4")
END 
ELSE BEGIN
   INSERT INTO dbo.sch_scores (school_id, ScoreID, ResultID, FormatID, Score, Status)
   VALUES ('1', '30836', '24614', '9', '4', 'Active') 
END

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sch_scores WHERE ResultID = '2' at line 1